# Is the whole function reverted if the ERC20 or ERC721 transferFrom fails?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, erc-721

I'm having some security doubts and confusion about the case of reverts. [As I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71077040/11569778), the whole changes of a function are reverted if the native `transfer` function fails. But what about the ERC721 and ERC20's `transfer`, `transferFrom`, `safeTransferFrom`?

For example:

1. If (1) or (2) fails, does the function breaks out and revert the `offer.isAccepted`?
2. If (2) fails, is weth transfer and therefore the whole function reverted?

   ```
   function acceptBid(uint256 _offerId) public nonReentrant {
   Offer storage offer = offers[_offerId];

   IERC20 weth = IERC20(0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab);
   IERC721 nftContract = IERC721(offer.nftContractAddress);

   address nftOwner = nftContract.ownerOf(offer.tokenId);

   offer.isAccepted = true; // *
   weth.transferFrom(
       address(offer.userAddress),
       payable(msg.sender),
       offer.price
   ); // (1)

   nftContract.transferFrom(
       address(this),
       offer.userAddress,
       offer.tokenId
   ); // (2)

   emit AcceptedOffer();}
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smart contract methods are executed in a transactional way. This means, if any of `revert`, `require` or failed `assert` is executed, then the whole transaction is meaned to revert, rolling back any changes made.

So:

- When `weth.transferFrom` reverts, `offer.isAccepted` will be cleared
- When `nftContract.transferFrom` reverts, `weth.transferFrom` will be rolled back and `offer.isAccepted` will be cleared.

Comment: [Note that it is possible to catch reverts in newer versions of Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/78563/620).